# Using variables for referencing objects in vb.net (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: vb.net, class, object, variables, instance

I'm having a problem when using variables in object names.

I have a Public class which is called "Tank"
In that class, there is a public property called "direction" of an integer type.

I keep getting the error:
"Tank is a type and cannot be used as an expression"
What I'm doing wrong here ?

```
Public Class mainroutines()

' Create Instances of tank  

Private Tank1 As New Tank()
Private Tank2 As New Tank()

'Loop trough objects and set the property value

dim i as integer
For i = 1 to 2
Tank(i).direction = 1
next i

End class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Tank(i)` is not equivalent to `Tank1`. You would need to make a list of tanks, add your instances to it, and access them that way.

```
Public Class mainroutines() 

' Create Instances of tank '  

Dim allTanks As List(Of Tank) = New List(Of Tank) 
allTanks.Add(New Tank())
allTanks.Add(New Tank())

'Loop through objects and set the property value '

dim i as integer 
For i = 1 to 2 
allTanks(i).direction = 1 
next i
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an array of Tanks:

```
Public Class mainroutines()

' Create Instances of tank  

Private Tank1 As New Tank()
Private Tank2 As New Tank()

'Loop trough objects and set the property value
Dim tanks() As Tank

tanks(0) = Tank1
tanks(1) = Tank2

For i As Integer = 1 To 2
   tanks(i).direction = 1
next

End class
```

If you're using Visual Studio 2008 then you could use:

```
Private Tank1 As New Tank() With { .Direction = 1}
Private Tank2 As New Tank() With { .Direction = 1}
```

So you don't need the For loop at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answers
The loop was just ment as an example.

I'm writing a game and I need a tank for player 1 and one for player 2. player is a variable of the integer type and is 1 or 2 depending on the player which is in control
In my code I often need to change the direction, or the x,y coordinates of the tank and I like to reference to the tank as

    Tank(player).direction
or
    Tank(player).X += 5
or 
    Tank(player).livesleft -= 1

I'll have to test your answers

Answer (score 0):

@ Jball

It needed a  small correction and your example worked just fine !
Exactly what I needed !

```
Dim alltanks As List(Of Tank) = New List(Of Tank)
```

Thanks a lot for your help !